# Why dataweave over template engines like Velocity/Freemarker/Thymeleaf

Tags: freemarker, velocity, dataweave

I see a broad adoption of Dataweave  which I feel is more of transformation library just like Freemarker or Velocity.
In case of DW Change in transformation logic would need change in code, the very same purpose template engines got popular at the first place to seperate logic and code so that we can change transformation logic without needing to rebuild/repackage our code (more deployment hassle).

Can anyone help me to point out few reasons as to why one would prefer DW .

Comment: Just to clarify, you don't need to have the DW code in the applications. In some cases, it makes sense to execute dynamic DW loading it from a DB, another API, or even getting the DW script as part of the API Request.

Comment: May I ask where do you see adoption outside the Mulesoft ecosystem?

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: If you're looking for a template engine for things like static websites, DataWeave definitely isn't the right choice. Use the right tool for the job. Also, while you can use DataWeave outside of Mule, I don't think I've seen anyone adopt DataWeave that hasn't adopted MuleSoft..

---

A few things to consider (and most of these I'm stating in the context of developing Mule applications):

These template engines are, typically, for outputting static text. If you're using it to output structured data rather than something like an HTML page.. you're probably doing it wrong. They aren't going to return structured data - they are going to return text. If you're at the very end of your flow and you're going to output that back out of the API or to a file, you're fine I suppose.. but if you want to actually be able to work with that output, you're going to have to convert the plain text to an actual object... introducing a lot of extra steps in this process when you could have just used DataWeave in the first place. Dataweave is especially beneficial when you want to do things like streaming because you're processing large payloads. Dataweave can understand JSON, XML, and CSV (the three most common data types I see) in a streamed format without any additional work, making it very easy to create efficient applications. The big difference between a template engine and a data transformation language is that one is for outputting text using structured data as input, and the other is for working with structured data on the input and outputting structured data that you can continue to work with. There is a reason that almost all of the template engine docs talk about building websites and not things like integrations.

The DataWeave engine is, as Aled indicated, built into the Mule runtime. Deeply so. You can use DataWeave in any field in any connector by default, even fields that don't have the `f(x)` button - *because* it's built into the runtime. This makes DataWeave what you could consider a first-class citizen within Mule, unlike something you will only be able to utilize either via connectors or by invoking java bridges/libraries.. which you do via DataWeave or a long series of connector operations.

The benefits you listed are also not things you can't do with DataWeave. You can VERY easily templatize and externalize DataWeave - for example, I have several DataWeave libraries in my maven repo I can include as dependencies. I've built several transformation services that use databases with DataWeave in order to do transformation, allowing me to change those transformations without modifying the app. You can also use dynamic DataWeave, where you use a template system to load specific parts of the script before running it. I've even taken it a step further and written a generic DataWeave script that I can use to do basic mappings without writing DataWeave - this allowed me to wrap a web UI around things pretty easily.

I wouldn't use DataWeave outside of MuleSoft unless you're a MuleSoft shop. If you are a MuleSoft shop, using the CLI to run your scripts, the same way you do with most interpreted languages, works fairly nicely - especially since you likely already have in-house expertise in DataWeave. The language is still niche enough that unless you've already adopted it for use in Mule applications I don't see any advantage in using it.

Docs / basic examples:

https://github.com/mulesoft-labs/data-weave-native

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/parse-template-reference

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dataweave-create-module

https://github.com/mikeacjones/transform-system-api

Answer (score 0):

Because it is the expression and transformation language embedded in Mule runtime. If you are using Mule it is also integrated with the IDE Anypoint Studio.

Outside Mule applications I don't think you can use DataWeave easily. You might want to go with the alternatives.

Comment: Agreed but i can use those templates inside Mule as a replacement for Dataweave and can have my transformations done without having to redeploy my application. What extra benefit does DW offer

Comment: Integration with the IDE gives you a graphical designer and preview. Integration with the runtime means that every expression in Mule 4 is a DataWeave expression. And you don't need to add libraries or code to call an external library. I think those are the advantages for DataWeave. You have to decide what is better for your particular needs, which may be different from others.

Comment: @darshankamat the thing is.. you CAN'T use those natively inside mule as a replacement for dataweave. You would have to use a bridge of some sort, which would make the application considerably more difficult to work with. It is far easier and more maintainable, in the long run, to use dataweave in MuleSoft applications.

Comment: I assume the question was purely related to transformation, not replacing the core expression language.

Comment: True enough, but a tool like Freemarker is really a text template engine. It isn't meant for outputting things like structured data, which is what a transformation language should be doing. Also, in Mule, you will still have to process that text into a structured object.. in a Mule app guess what is going to do that? So you're adding a lot of extra steps.. especially since MuleSoft doesn't have official connectors for any of those as far as I'm aware. To repeat.. these engines are good for outputting things like static text, like HTML... not structured data you intend to work with.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you.